# Is it posible to set environtment variable without file?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nginx, environment-variables, environment

I've try that node.js load environtment variable from file .env. how to set environtment variable without file ?

Comment: You can assign environment variables on the fly by running the command

Comment: set NODE_ENV=production

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you are looking for but you can use [Node Foreman](https://www.npmjs.com/package/foreman) or [Heroku Start](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) to auto load your .env file before launching your node application.

If you don't want to do that they you can use something like this:

```
fs = require('fs');
path = require('path');

function readEnv() {
  return new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject) {
      let envPath = path.join(process.cwd(), '.env');
      fs.readFile(envPath, 'utf8',
        (err, data) => {
          if (err) {
            return reject(err);
          }

          let env = {};
          data.split(/[\r\n]+/g).forEach(
            (line) => {
              line = line.trim();
              if (line) {
                let idx = line.indexOf('=');
                if (idx > -1) {
                  let key = line.substr(0,idx);
                  let value = line.substr(idx+1);
                  env[key] = value;
                }
                else {
                  env[line] = '';
                }
              }
            }
          );

          resolve(env);
        }
      );
    }
  );
}

function processEnv() {
  return readEnv().then(
    (env) => {
      Object.keys(env).forEach(
        (key) => {
          process.env[key] = env[key];
        }
      );
      return true;
    }
  ).catch(
    (err) => {
      console.error(err);
    }
  );
}

module.exports = processEnv;
```

Comment: thx, i want my nodejs project load environtment variable not from file but from other somthing. on case PHP project i have try this by using fastcgi in nginx, so the php project load environtment from nginx. but for node js is it posible to do like that ?

Comment: How do you want to load the environment variables?  Do you want to get them from a different server using http client?

Comment: i do not know yet, can it load from nginx like PHP or by another method ?